# How to calculate distance in relation to the size of the window

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

i want to fit UIButton for all iPhone Screens :

- iPhone 4s
- iPhone 5
- iPhone 5s
- iPhone 6s Plus

How i can calculate distance in relation to the size of the screen ?

I need to fit Pause Button and Record Button for all iPhone Screens.

Actually , it seen perfect on iPhone 6 but on iPhone 6 plus it seen very different.

**Im not using with Storyboard! i need to do it only with code is very important!**

**iPhone 6 :**

[image]

**iPhone 6 Plus :**

[image]

**GameViewController:**

Pause Button :

```
 func addPauseButton() {
        //create Pause Button
        PauseButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 + 150,self.view!.frame.size.height/2 - 315 ,30,30))

        PauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause-Button.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        PauseButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressedPauseGame:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(PauseButton)
}
```

Record Button :

```
func addRecordButton() {

            startRecordingButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 + 155 ,self.view!.frame.size.height/2 - 275 ,25,25))

            startRecordingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Record-Off.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            startRecordingButton.addTarget(self, action: "startRecordingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            self.view.addSubview(startRecordingButton)

            stopRecordingButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 + 155 ,self.view!.frame.size.height/2 - 275 ,25,25))

            stopRecordingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Record-On.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            stopRecordingButton.addTarget(self, action: "stopRecordingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            self.view.addSubview(stopRecordingButton)

    }
```

Comment: You said you can't use auto layout because of Sprite Kit (read in comments)? https://github.com/mgrebenets/SpriteKitAutoLayout

Answer (score 0):

the "StoryBoard" is your friend,  take the time now to learn how to use storyBoards  to save yourself a great deal of time in the future,  see this image below,  all buttons,  exactly in the same place on all devices,   with zero coding effort.  kind of brilliant idea,  that some old timers in coding are not using,  (or coders too used to coding every x,y spot on a computer screen)

unfortunately some of those old timers get into Apple,  then we lose stuff...   like xCode snapshots...   too bad really,  so use it or lose it.

[image]

Comment: im not using with storyboard. I'm working with sprite kit and i can't to use with auto layout. I'm working with ViewController and i know that possible to do it without storyboard

Comment: you can easily use storyboards with spriteKit, or any other kit for that matter,  you can even do half programatic layout and half story board, and you do not have to use autoLayout.    it can be a view inside of a view inside of another view,  some laid out programatically for exactly what needs to be presented on the screen.  --- some say that if the menu or buttons are simple then just use spritekit,  but I think even with a couple buttons, this saves you time/effort,  simply point the button at code to execute in spritkit,  and spritkit view setup to work inside of view of storyboard view.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the actual presented view only becomes valid in the will-layout or will-appear view controller callbacks, so, if you create UI objects in code, you may need to (re)adjust the frame rects of your UI objects to become your desired proportion of the view rect at that time (in those later callbacks, not earlier methods close to init or launch time).

There are also view transition callbacks for when the user rotates the display or does other things to the app window size on newer iPads.

Comment: So I need to fit to each a separate screen?

Comment: You need to (re)fit each UI object's frame each time a view is presented or otherwise changes.

Comment: Do you have view layout or transition delegate methods?  Do you know your desired UI frame rect proportions?  Any code needs you to do those first.